# Spring Boot/Eclipse index.html: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, controller

I'm following this tutorial to integrate Spring Boot with AngularJS:

https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j

I built the Spring Boot starter with STS in Eclipse/Photon.  My Eclipse project looks like this:

[image]

My "Home" Controller looks like this:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Per the screenshot above, I have an "index.html" in src/main/resources/static/views.

My application.properties defines spring.mvc.view.prefix and .suffix:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .html
```

There are no errors or warnings when I right-click the Eclipse project and "Run As > Spring App".

But when I browse to localhost:8080/home, I get:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Nov 03 13:40:19 PDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Why am I getting a "404" trying to access "/home"?

Is there anything "special" I need to do in Eclipse, with my Eclipse project?

What are some good strategies for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are not using templating engine such as `thymeleaf`.

Try the following and it should fix your problem.

1. move your `index.html` to `src/main/resources/static`. This is the location from where static resources like `HTML` file will be served automatically.
2. You can remove those two lines that you define on `application.properties` file.

Comment: You'e correct - I'm *NOT* using Thymeleaf (server-side templating).  I want to use [Angular](https://angular.io/) instead.  My challenge is getting "Eclipse > Run As Spring Boot App" to serve the HTML which would, in turn, call my Angular UI.  My "Home" controller doesn't seem to be calling my view's "index.html" :(

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Angular still isn't working correctly ... and I have no idea why the author of the tutorial  wrote it the way it did.  But yes - I 1) Removed the controller, 2) removed the spring.mvc.view.* parameters from application.properties, 3) moved index.html directly under resources/static, 4) deleted the "views" directory... and I'm able to see the index page, and it successfully loads the needed .css and .js files.  So thank you - question answered!